# how to get reference to the Method being invoked in jersey

Tags: java, jersey, resteasy

I'm developing a **REST** based web service using `jersey`. I want to implement role-based authorization for this web service.

Now suppose i have one method `getUsers()` :

```
@RolesAllowed("ADMIN")
@Path("\Users")
@GET
public void getUsers() {
  // some code.
}
```

`getUsers()` will be invoked for a `GET \Users` request.

After getting the request i will **authenticate** the client using it's **credentials** and will determine his role then i have to decide to let the request pass or reject.

Getting credentials and authenticating user is not a problem, i need a way to get reference to the method which will be executed for a request.

So that i can check its @RolesAllowed annotation to grant or reject access.

In `RestEasy` we have `PreProcessInterceptor` interface which has following method :

```
 preProcess(HttpRequest request, ResourceMethod methodInvoked)
```

`ResourceMethod's` `getMethod()` gives us reference to the method being invoked in our case `getUsers()`. Using this `Method` reference i can check the annotations an do stuff.

Now my question is how can i do it in `Jersey`?

What is the **Jersey** alternative of **RestEasy** `PreProcessInterceptor`?

Comment: from your description it seems a good task to be implemented with aspect oriented programming paradigm. When a get request is issued, you intercept it, check the user and let the method to be executed (or not).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can inject [ExtendedUriInfo](https://jersey.java.net/apidocs/latest/jersey/org/glassfish/jersey/server/ExtendedUriInfo.html) and call [getMatchedResourceMethod](https://jersey.java.net/apidocs/latest/jersey/org/glassfish/jersey/server/ExtendedUriInfo.html#getMatchedResourceMethod%28%29). This should work also in (post-matching) filter, so you should be able to use JAX-RS [ContainerRequestFilter](https://jersey.java.net/apidocs/latest/jersey/javax/ws/rs/container/ContainerRequestFilter.html).

Then call [ResourceMethod](https://jersey.java.net/apidocs/latest/jersey/org/glassfish/jersey/server/model/ResourceMethod.html).getInvocable().getHandlingMethod() and you can check whatever you need :)